# Sum of reciprocal powers of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Extending this: [Use of the Reciprocal Fibonacci constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145285/use-of-the-reciprocal-fibonacci-constant)

Can we get a closed form of $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{F_k^k}?$$

By root test, this infinite series converges.

By adding large, say until first $100$ terms I got the value as $2.137\ldots$. Source: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7B100%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7BF_k%5Ek%7D)

Comment: The fibonacci sequence has an explicit definition in the form $a(b^x-c^x)$, so if you can find a method of finding the sum of the reciprocals of the numbers in that form for $x$ in arithmetic progression, you should be able to do it.

Comment: @Frpzzd I couldn't even proceed with just the reciprocal fibonacci summation. Is that already proved?

Comment: Not that I know of. Wolfram Alpha won't give a summation formula.

Comment: Let $B_k = \left(\frac{10}{5+\sqrt{5}}\right)^n < \frac{1}{F_k}$ then you can get a bound from $\sum B_k$ which is an geometric progression

Comment: There's not even a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{F_k}$ (at least, it hasn't been found) so I highly doubt there's a closed form for this one

Comment: @gt6989b I think you meant $B_k = \left(\frac{10}{5+\sqrt{5}}\right)^k$? And how is $\left(\frac{10}{5+\sqrt{5}}\right)^k < \frac{1}{F_k}$?

Comment: A version of the bound @gt6989b is referring to appears in this older question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269082/137524. (I say version because it's not quite the same.)